# Verilog code for shift and add multiplier

Tags: verilog, iverilog

Good day guys, I'm created a Shift - And - Add multiplier. I'm confused on why my output is wrong and always at 85. Is it something with the Test bench ?  It's working by the way.

new1.v

```
`define M ACC[0]
module mult4X4 (Clk, St, Mplier, Mcand, Done, Result);

input Clk,St;
input [3:0] Mplier, Mcand;
output Done;
output [7:0] Result;

reg [3:0] State;
reg [8:0] ACC;

initial
begin
    State = 0;
    ACC = 0;
end

always @(posedge Clk)
begin
    case (State)
        0:
            begin
                if(St == 1'b1)
                begin
                    ACC[8:4] <= 5'b00000 ;
                    ACC[3:0] <= Mplier ;
                    State <= 1;
                end
            end
        1,3,5,7 :
            begin
                if(`M==1'b1)
                begin
                    ACC[8:4] <= {1'b0, ACC[7:4]} + Mcand ;
                    State <= State +1;
                end
                else
                begin
                    ACC <= {1'b0, ACC[8:1]};
                    State <= State + 2;
                end
            end
        2,4,6,8 :
            begin
                ACC <= {1'b0, ACC[8:1]};
                State <= State +1;
            end
        9:
            begin
                State <= 0;
            end
        endcase
    end

    assign Done = (State == 9) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0 ;
    assign Result = (State == 9) ? ACC[7:0] : 8'b01010101;
endmodule
```

tb_new1.v

```
module tb_mult4X4;
    reg Clk,St,nReset;
    reg [3:0] Mplier;
    reg [3:0] Mcand;
    wire Done;
    wire [7:0] Result;

    mult4X4 UUT (Clk,St,Mplier,Mcand,Done,Result);

    initial begin
        $dumpfile ("mult4X4.vpd");
        $dumpvars;
    end
    initial
        Clk = 0;

    always
        #5 Clk =~Clk;
    initial begin

        nReset = 0;
        St = 0; 
        Mcand = 4'b1101;
        Mplier = 4'b1011;

        #10
        nReset = 1;
        St = 1;
        Mcand = 4'b1111;
        Mplier = 4'b1001;

        #10

        Mcand = 4'b0101;
        Mplier = 4'b1010;

        #10

        Mcand = 4'b1111;
        Mplier = 4'b1111;

        #10
        Mcand = 4'b1101;
        Mplier = 4'b1010;

        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

I ran though the code so many times and everything seems to be following my FSM. Can anyone please point out where went wrong. Really confused on this one

Answer (score 1):

`#10` is way to short. Your RTL requires 10 clocks to complete but you change the input every clock (half clk is `#5`).
Use `#100` or better yet `@(posedge Done);` (which makes the test-bench to wait for done regardless the number of clocks that is required).